# Maximizing power from batteries to a DC Motor?

Tags: dc-motor, dc-dc-converter

I have this [DC motor](http://www.pittman-motors.com/Brush-DC-Motors/14204-Brush-DC-Motor.aspx) (the 38.2V version). I want to maximize the power put into it for 10-20 seconds, but I can only use 4 lithium 9V batteries. I know that as the batteries discharge, the voltage decreases.

From my research, I found some possibilities:

1. Charge capacitors, which discharge into the motor.
2. Use a Buck Converter, which would give me more current, but less voltage.
3. Use a Boost Converter, which would give me the inverse of #2.
4. Something else?

How would I do this?

Comment: What is the discharge rate of your batteries?

Comment: 1000 mA continuous (pdf datasheet link: http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/la522.pdf)

Comment: Do you have an idea of what speed you are going to run the motor at? Any idea of the load?

Comment: The load is around 1.3kg

Comment: Rotational load? Its in oz*in. And the speed of the motor... in krpm

Comment: I'd like to operate at max, so 26 oz-in and 3.23 krpm

Comment: Thats not how it works, did you see the motor loading curve on the webpage? You can have torque or speed but not both. The load on the motor is what sets the power in the system, once you know how much power the motor is going to use, you can then figure out how to deliver that power.

Comment: I see. I want to operate at 150 oz-in, which would be 1000rpm, right?

Comment: No, the motor is VERY inefficient at 38V and 1000rpm, the 26 oz/in at 3230rpm was correct. However there is no credible way to run a 62W motor from four PP3 batteries.  Capacitors with sufficiently low ESR might : 2A for 20S = 40 Coulombs, so decide on an acceptable voltage drop and that gives you a capacitance. For 2V, that would be 20F, which at 36V is quite a capacitor. The best way is throw out those batteries and start again.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, unless there is a more energy dense battery that can be bought at a grocery store and is less than 150g, this is all I can use. If I could use something like a 16850, I would.

Comment: By the time you've found room for that 20F capacitor those 18650s will be looking pretty small.  Alternatively look at model electric flight battery packs (rechargeable) made of smaller Li cells or even AA NiMH, they will have higher power density than your PP3s.

Comment: Your motor weighs almost 1kg. Why do the batteries have to weigh less than 150g?

Comment: @BruceAbbott the 150g is a hard limit for batteries that I didn't make.

Comment: That hard limit (somebody else's design decision) is called a "poisoned chalice". Drinking from it is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run the motor at 38.2V * 2.32A = 89W. However you are limited to batteries weighing less than 150g that can be bought at a grocery store, which cannot deliver anywhere near that kind of power. Therefore the only choice you have is to slowly charge up some device (not a battery!) that can then be discharged at 89W for 10-20 seconds.

The obvious choice for the storage device is a supercap. To deliver 89W for 20 seconds it needs to store at least 89*20 = 1780 joules of energy. In practice you will need more to compensate for conversion losses and to maintain a reasonable voltage throughout the discharge. Energy stored = 1/2CV<sup>2</sup>, so 2F at 50V (or 8F at 25V etc.) should be enough. Supercaps are usually rated at much lower voltages, but you can wire several in series/parallel to get the desired operating voltage and capacitance.

How many caps? Using commonly available 10F 2.5V supercaps you need 20 in series to get 50V, but as total capacitance is divided by the number in series that only gives you 0.5F at 50V. So you will need 4 of these banks in parallel to get 2F - a total of 80 capacitors!

Using a lower voltage won't help because the amount of energy stored is the same no matter how you connect the capacitors. However running a buck/boost regulator at a low input/output differential is generally more efficient than running a boost regulator from a much lower voltage. Using higher voltage also reduces current so you can use thinner wires. You need a regulator (buck, boost, or buck/boost depending on the operating voltage range of your capacitor bank) because voltage will drop as the capacitors discharge.

To charge the capacitor bank you could use another switching regulator with current limiting. Your lithium batteries can deliver about 24W (6V @1A x4) so recharging the capacitor bank will probably take at least 1.5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks! So what I want to do is batteries => cap bank => regulator => motor, right? If I wanted to go from 21.6V to 38.2V, I would want to use a boost converter, right? Also, do you have any resources on calculating component values for boost converters?

Comment: Yes, that's it. http://www.daycounter.com/LabBook/BoostConverter/Boost-Converter-Equations.phtml